# Create label expression that sums an attribute for features in a group?

Tags: arcgis-pro, labeling, arcade

I have pipes that have been assigned to a group (1, 2, 3, 4, etc).
Each pipe also has a "Length"  attribute.

I am working in Pro 3.2.0

For each pipe group, I want to have a single label that shows:

*Group [X]*

*Total Footage: [Y]'*

Typically, I would get all of my groups finalized and then get a table of summary stats  by group number to join to the the feature class.  I could then use the joined summary stats in the label expression.

**But I want to know if it can be done on the fly *in the label expression* since my groups are subject to change and I want to avoid re running summary stats every time a pipe is reassigned to a different group.**

I trying to make this work as a single label class - not a separate label class for each group.

Something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
var sumField = "mylengthfield"; // Replace with the actual field name you want to sum

// Use GroupBy() to group features based on a field
var groups = GroupBy($feature, "MyGroupField"); // Replace with the actual field for grouping

// Initialize the sum variable
var totalSum = 0;

// Loop through each group and sum the specified field
for (var group in groups) {
totalSum += Sum(group, sumField);}

return totalSum;
```

Comment: [GroupBy](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/featureset_functions/#groupby) includes optional statistic parameters, which could calculate the sum for you.  `var groups = GroupBy($feature, "MyGroupField", [{name: "mylengthfield_sum", expression: "mylengthfield", statistic: "SUM"}])`.  The result is a FeatureSet, which you could use to create custom labels.

Comment: the documentation seems to state support in pop ups, but not necessarily in the Pro labeling interface. I guess I'm looking for proof that it works there before putting more time into something that may be explicitly not supported.

Comment: actually, it seems that it's not supported after all : "FeatureSet functions and profile variables are not included in rendering profiles, such as visualization and **labeling**, because they require querying data from a server or database. Allowing these functions in rendering profiles would severely hinder the performance of apps executing the expression."

Comment: If performance, which usually is, important, then the approach with joining summary tables will yield the best performance in labelling.  Computing sums on the fly only really works in my opinion when the data is numerically small. If your labels are for the whole of Europe then when you zoom out it will try to render them all, unless you have a scale threshold on the labels. You might get away with it in Pro but if your intentions are to upload to AGOL then you need to considered network performance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using the Python interpreter rather than Arcade due to the limited capabilities in the Arcade Profile for labeling.

I created random points with two groups and random values:

[image]

Then in the label settings, using the Python language, I changed the FindLabel function to:

```
import arcpy

def FindLabel ( [group_] ):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(r"C:\SO\Data.gdb\Labels", ["value"], "group_ = '{0}'".format([group_])) as sc:
        total = 0
        for row in sc:
            total = total + row[0]
    return "Group Total ({0}): {1}".format([group_], total)
```

The function uses a search cursor to calculate the sum for the group value of the feature.  Returning a string denoting the total:

[image]

If you're comfortable using Python rather than Arcade, then this would give you the desired sum for each group in the label class.

Comment: Since the cursor points to the full path of the feature class,  this does not honor a definition query on the layer in the map, but for my purposes, that is OK. Thanks!

Comment: You can always modify the where statement for the cursor to include your def query and the group value.